# Azure AD B2C Graph API: Create User + Login At Same Time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We are building an android/ios app that will authenticate with B2C.  We will be creating our users programmatically with something like below:

1. API: invite user
2. USER: enters invite into app
3. API: confirms invitation info
4. USER: enters account info (i.e. password)
5. API + B2C/Graph: creates new user
6. USER: asked to login with new account (to get tokens) - will launch B2C hosted login

**Question:** Is there any way we could skip this last login step by using Graph to both create the user **and** get initial Access + Refresh tokens for the newly created user?  See possible highlighted below.

My sense is that this is possible, but we'd need to mark our B2C application as **Allow public client flows** and then use the ROPC flow to get tokens programmatically on behalf of the user.  This would likely lower the security posture of this B2C app somewhat.  Are there other options?

[image]

Comment: you can use OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C, for getting the access token and refresh token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-a-token

Comment: @MehtabSiddique - agreed, but that flow requires the end user to provide their username and password.  On initial account signup, we were hoping to avoid that step.  We just got enough info from the end user to create their account for them in B2C, and were hoping to (securely) return with their initial access token and refresh tokens.  That might not be realistic (or secure), but that's why I'm asking.